# Why is "would" missing in a subjunctive sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

> Two years later the opportunity came for him to take a distinctly American look at the Old World. In New York City the steamship Quaker City prepared to sail on a pleasure cruise to Europe and the Holy Land. For the first time, a sizable group of United States citizens planned to journey as tourists-a milestone, off sorts, in a country's development. Twain was assigned to accompany them, as correspondent for a California newspaper. **If readers expected the usual glowing travelogue, they were sorely surprised.**

This paragraph is an extract from a text called *Mark Twain-Mirror of America*, however, the last sentence seems a bit odd to me since I think it is a subjunctive. Therefore, it should be rephrased into "If readers expected the usual glowing travelogue, they would be sorely surprised".

Comment: It's fine as it is, and your example is fine too. It's not subjunctive, though, and your suggested alternant is simply a remote conditional.

Comment: @Billj Why isn't it a subjunctive?

Comment: The subjunctive contains a plain (infinitive) form of the verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** kept informed. Your example uses the past tense. Also, the subjunctive only applies to "be" and 3rd person singular subjects.

Comment: @Billj But I was trying to say the past subjunctive, not the present.

Comment: The past subjunctive uses "were", as in "If I **were** you, I'd avoid it". There is no "were" in your example. In the original example, "were" is a past tense verb, not the subjunctive "were".